# Split and find specific text?

Tags: vb.net

ok so i've made a HTTPWEBREQUEST and i've made the source of the result show in a richtextbox, Now say i have this in the richtextbox

```
<p>Short URL: <code><a href="http://URL.me/u/eywnp">http://URL.me/u/eywnp</a></code></p>
```

How would i go about just getting the "http://URL.me/u/eywnp" ive tried split but didnt work, guess i'm doing it wrong?

NOTE the URL will be different everytime

Comment: MsgBox(Split(RichTextBox1.Text, "<p>Short URL: <code><a href=", ">"))

Answer (score 4):

`Split` isn’t the right tool for the job. It will result in a rather complex piece of code that’s quite brittle (meaning it will break as soon as there’s the slightest change in the input).

For a robust, well-written solution you need to parse the HTML properly. Luckily there exist canned solutions for that: [The HtmlAgilityPack library](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex).

```
Dim doc As New HtmlDocument()
doc.LoadHtml(yourCode)
Dim result = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")(0)("href")
```

The only complicated part here is the string `"//a[@href]"`. This is an [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) string. XPath strings are a mini-language that is used to address elements in an HTML or XML document. They are conceptually similar to file paths (like `C:\Users\foo\Documents\file.txt`) but with a slightly different syntax.

The XPath simply selects all the `<a>` elements having a `href` attribute from your document. Then you can grab the first of that collection and retrieve the `href` attribute’s value.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all your help, i did find a solution and i used

```
 Dim iStartIndex, iEndIndex As Integer
        With RichTextBox1.Text
            iStartIndex = .IndexOf("<p>Short URL: <code><a href=") + 29
            iEndIndex = .IndexOf(""">", iStartIndex)
            Clipboard.SetText(.Substring(iStartIndex, iEndIndex - iStartIndex))

        End With
```

works perfect so  far

Comment: See my reply for why this is a bad idea.

Comment: +1 for sharing your solution (which is fine as long as the input *really* doesn't change). (+1 for Konrad as well, but that goes without saying.)